# max value in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, max

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(Name, '-') AS Name,
    ISNULL(q.QName, '-') AS Education,
    ISNULL(Grade, '-') AS Grade
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT qname,max (code) FROM table3 group by Code) q ON ed.code = q.code
WHERE vw.id = 125
```

There are 3 records in table2 now I want to get max code from table2    and this shows an error

No column name was specified for column 2 of 'q'
     Invalid column name QName

Comment: The error is correct. You don't have a code or QName column in your q. You should change it to 

`LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(code) AS code FROM table3) AS q ON `

This should fix the missing code column. But i don't know where to get your QName from. More Information about your tales would be useful.

Comment: check update question

Comment: `LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(code) AS code FROM table3) AS q ON ed.code = q.code` should fix the `invalid column name code`. But you don't have a QName in this subquery what are you are using in `ISNULL(q.QName, '-')`

Comment: SELECT qname, max (code) FROM table3 group by QName

Comment: Change this `left JOIN (SELECT qname,max (code) FROM table3 group by Code) q ON ` to this `left JOIN (SELECT qname,max (code) as max_code FROM table3 group by Code) q ON ` and add `max_code` to `SELECT` part. The problem is in unnamed column `max (code)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(Name, '-') AS Name,
    ISNULL(q.QName, '-') AS Education,
    ISNULL(Grade, '-') AS Grade
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
        ON t1.id = t2.id
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT QName, MAX(code) AS code FROM table3 GROUP BY QName) q 
        ON ed.code = q.code
WHERE vw.id = 125
```